# Error "Cannot find path from" during program start up

Tags: powershell

Why is this code not working as was planned? 
What is powershell's auto variables for place where the target directory the script is running in?

```
Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot -PassThru
$file1.text="$PSScriptRoot\MIK_Autokontinent.xml
```

During startup, the program return error cannot find the path from `c:\MIK_Autokontinent.xml`
but the file is located in `c:\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml`

This line is returning the error

```
$inputpecentw1.Text = [xml](Get-Content $file1.text) | ForEach-Object { $_.SelectNodes(' //FieldCostOptions/IncreaseCost') | ForEach-Object { $_.GetAttribute("Percent") } } | Out-String
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the file in your root directory but the program is in the `program` folder. If your script is in the same folder as the file itself, just use the filename as reference like this `$file1.text="MIK_Autokontinent.xml"`
But in case you want to do this the way you are doing and from the root folder do it like this `$file1.text="$PSScriptRoot\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml"`.

Comment: but if i run this script from different place. How do i remake the program that it run from any place? How do i make exe file from script that  it work from any directory?

Comment: I explained that in the example I provided at the end of my answer, use `$file1.text="$PSScriptRoot\program\MIK_Autokontinent.xml"` if you want to find the file from your root folder, which means it can be found when the script is ran outside of the folder itself.

Comment: Do you still get an error about the path and if you do, can you provide it here?

Comment: PS C: \ program \ t> C: \ program \ prg.ps1
Get-Content: Cannot find the path "C: \ program \ program \ MIK_AutoPremium.xml" because it does not exist.
C: \ program \ prg.ps1: 59 character: 37
+ $ inputpecentw2.Text = [xml] (Get-Content $ file2.text) | ForEac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (C: \ program \ program \ MIK_AutoPremium.xml: String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: PathNotFound, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 
Cannot call a method for an expression with a NULL value.

Comment: when we make exe from .ps1 we lost all paths? why?

Comment: Weird, why don't you use direct path like `$file1.text="C:/program/MIK_AutoPremium.xml"`